# What can I do about missing libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.la?

Tags: 10.10, compiling, libraries

I'm trying to compile an application (peekabot) from source on a clean install of 10.10 (this is under VirtualBox on OS X, but I don't think that this is a problem). When it performs a linking step it fails because of a missing static library:

```
libtool: link: cannot find the library `/usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.la' or unhandled argument `/usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.la'
```

I have libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev installed, hence the worry.

The reference to the library appears to have been added as a dependency of libgtkglextmm and libgdkglextmm:

```
grep "libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.la" /usr/lib/*.la

/usr/lib/libgdkglextmm-x11-1.2.la:dependency_libs=' /usr/lib/libgdkglext-x11-1.0.la /usr/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.la /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.la /usr/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.la /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.la /usr/lib/libpangox-1.0.la /usr/lib/libpango-1.0.la /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.la /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.la /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.la -lGLU -lXmu -lXt -lSM -lICE /usr/lib/libgdkmm-2.4.la /usr/lib/libpangomm-1.4.la /usr/lib/libglibmm-2.4.la /usr/lib/libcairomm-1.0.la /usr/lib/libcairo.la -lfreetype -lz -lfontconfig -lpng12 -lxcb-render-util -lXrender -lX11 -lpixman-1 /usr/lib/libsigc-2.0.la'

/usr/lib/libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2.la:dependency_libs=' /usr/lib/libgdkglextmm-x11-1.2.la /usr/lib/libgtkglext-x11-1.0.la /usr/lib/libgdkglext-x11-1.0.la /usr/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.la /usr/lib/libatk-1.0.la /usr/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.la /usr/lib/libfreetype.la /usr/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.la /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.la /usr/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.la /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.la /usr/lib/libpangox-1.0.la /usr/lib/libpango-1.0.la /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.la /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.la /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.la -lGLU -lXmu -lXt -lSM -lICE /usr/lib/libgtkmm-2.4.la /usr/lib/libgiomm-2.4.la /usr/lib/libgdkmm-2.4.la /usr/lib/libatkmm-1.6.la /usr/lib/libpangomm-1.4.la /usr/lib/libcairomm-1.0.la /usr/lib/libcairo.la -lfreetype -lpng12 -lxcb-render-util -lXrender -lX11 -lpixman-1 /usr/lib/libglibmm-2.4.la /usr/lib/libsigc-2.0.la -lz -lfontconfig'
```

But the referenced static library is missing from my system. So, is there a way to get this library that I'm missing, or is there some other workaround I can use?

thanks, Nick

Comment: The developer of peekabot has now filed this as a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtkglextmm/+bug/662572

Comment: In the end I worked around this but editing the .la files to change the linkage to libgdk_pixbuf-2.0 to be a dynamic link rather than static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My fix for this was to open the files

```
/usr/lib/libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2.la
 /usr/lib/libgdkglextmm-x11-1.2.la
```

and replace any occurrences of

```
 /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.la
```

with

```
-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
```

However, the bug should now be fixed properly:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtkglextmm/+bug/662572

Answer (score 0):

Are you building a 32-bit application on 64-bit by chance?  This question reminds me of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdk-pixbuf/+bug/641056) which I'm not 100% sure we fixed this cycle.

Comment: This is a 32-bit install of Ubuntu and I have not set any arch flags for the build. I assume that this means the above isn't the problem, unless something nefarious is going on under the hood.